# How to Add Header Title to SharePoint Document Sets

Tags: document-set, branding

I would like to add a header title to Document Sets in SharePoint.  Can this be done and if so how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify the Welcome Page for Document Sets.
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Customize-the-Welcome-Page-for-a-document-set-fc4e5d63-b168-4ece-bbf6-851a2ac07e31

Programmatically:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34fa3673-45e9-4477-9713-b0b6bde35097/programmatically-set-document-set-welcome-page-view?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: The question is up to the point and I provided the requested info in an up to the point way. If the answer doesn't work on this community, please remove it and leave it unanswered.